# Ripple effect activated on backpressed

Tags: android, android-imagebutton, rippledrawable

as title says, how to make my ripple effect on `ImageButton` (ripple effect assigned to this ImageButton) activated on `backpressed()` without back to the previous activity

Comment: share some code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

with a bit of logic you could achieve that easily. what i thought of is that you have a method lets call it `doSomething();`

```
boolean onBackpressed = false;
private void doSomthing() {
    if(onBackpressed){
        finish();
    }else{
        // do anything else that the button wants to do;
    }
}
```

now `onBackpressed()` you could do this

```
@Override public void onBackpressed() {
    onBackpressed = true;
    myImageButton.performClick(); // myImageButton.callOnClick()
}
```

P.S: that i didn't call `super.onBackpressed();` so we can control the back press without existing the app.

of course your `imageButton` click `listener` calls `doSomething()` method.

Comment: is bot working, I still didn't see ripple effect activated on backpress button

Comment: call button.setPressed(true) before finish